# Inserting a very long Excel table into Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a very long excel (2003) s/sheet with in excess of 600 rows that I want to paste into an MS Word document (also 2003).  However, I want to ensure that:

1) The header row appears automatically at the top of each page.

2) The s/sheet automatically formats to the correct page width (the one I have is slightly wider than my Word page).

This can obviously be done manually by cutting and pasting each page seperately but this is very laborious and time consuming and I once saw somebody achieve this automatically (maybe with a macro) but have been unable to locate them, or the methodology.  Can anyone please assist?

Thanks in advance,
Fred.

Answer (score 2):

1. To get the header row on each page, select the header row, right-click, select Table Properties. Go to the Row tab on the top, and check to box next to "Repeat as header row at the top of each page".
2. Try right-clicking the table and select Autofit to contents. It really depends on what's in your table and you'll likely need to manually play with margins and font sizes. Not sure how to automate that.